# DecodeJson with All Failed Decoding Attempts?

Tags: scala, argonaut

Given the following from the `argonaut` [docs](http://argonaut.io/doc/codec/):

```
import argonaut._
import Argonaut._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

implicit def PersonDecodeJson: DecodeJson[Person] =
   jdecode2L(Person.apply)("name", "age")

scala> Json.obj("name" -> jString("bob"), 
                 "age" -> jString("whoops - not a number.")
       ).as[Person]
res1: argonaut.DecodeResult[Person] = DecodeResult(Left((Int,CursorHistory(List(El(CursorOpDownField(age),true))))))

scala> Json.obj("name" -> jNumber(42), 
                "age" -> jString("whoops - not a number.")
       ).as[Person]
res2: argonaut.DecodeResult[Person] = DecodeResult(Left((String,CursorHistory(List(El(CursorOpDownField(name),true))))))
```

In `res2`, it appears that `age`'s incorrect type, i.e. expected number, but got string, did not show up in the cursor output. In other words, it seems to me that the decoding failed fast on `name`.

Is there an "out of the box" `DecodeJson` that will return all failed decoding attempts?